# Displaying ng-repeat items in random order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm using radio buttons to give possible answers to a question, and they need to be displayed in a random order so that the correct answer isn't always in the same place.

When using orderBy to put them in a random order however, they will change position every time one of the radio buttons is clicked, how can I prevent them from being reordered, or is there a better way to display the radio buttons randomly?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat='n in list | orderBy:random'>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' ng-model='abc.ans' value='{{n}}'>
      {{n}}
    </label>  
  </div>
  <p>
  {{abc.ans}}
  </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.abc = {};
    $scope.list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    $scope.random = function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }
}
```

JSFiddle demonstrating the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/o041kp7p/

Comment: The problem is that your orderBy function has to return the same result all the time. your random will just rand to infinity. You should add a '_my_order' in each item of the list. If you set '1' in the first n._my_order, '0' in the second, the second will be displayed in first.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: are the solutions ok or need something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/o041kp7p/1/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {


$scope.abc = {};
    $scope.abc.ok = 'wat';
    // you have to store values in an object (to add a column '_order')
    $scope.list = [
      { 'value' : 'a'}, 
      { 'value' : 'b'},
      { 'value' : 'c'},
      { 'value' : 'd'},
      { 'value' : 'e'},
      { 'value' : 'f'},
      { 'value' : 'g'}];


    // the list of indexes you can pick in (to generate the '_order' )
    var list_index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    // affect 1 index to each element
    var j = 0;
    while(list_index.length > 0) {
        var i = Math.floor(list_index.length * Math.random());
      if(i >= list_index.length)
        i --;

      var val = list_index.splice(i, 1);
      $scope.list[j]._order = val[0];
      j ++;
    }
}
```

The trick is to:

- store a column '_order' in the elements you are ordering
- randomize once their index
- use that column '_order' in the orderBy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Just needed a small change. You are having problems because the list is sorted every time the model value changes. 
http://jsfiddle.net/himanshu1691/o041kp7p/4/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
  <div ng-repeat='n in list' >
    <label>
      <input type='radio' ng-model='abc.ans' value='{{n}}'>
      {{n}}
    </label>  
  </div>
  <p>
  {{abc.ans}}
  </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope , orderByFilter) {
        $scope.abc = {};
    $scope.abc.ok = 'wat';
    $scope.list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    $scope.random = function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }
    $scope.list = orderByFilter($scope.list,$scope.random);

}
```

This way list in randomly sorted only once during controller load.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the logic goes as follows:

1. get the length of the original array say 'nums[].length'.
2. generate random index till the length of the array nums[].
3. parse the array(num[random index]). push the element to second array, say 'arr[]', if the element does not already exist in arr[].

PS: works for array with unique elements though. Effective way for randomly parsing JSON array.

```js
$scope.nums=['1','2','3','4','5'];
 $scope.arr=[];
 console.log($scope.nums.length+" "+$scope.arr.length);
 var a=$scope.nums.length;
 var b=$scope.arr.length;
 while(a>b)
 {  console.log("inside while");
    $scope.randvar=Math.floor(Math.random() * a);
    console.log("randvar"+$scope.randvar)
    if($scope.arr.indexOf($scope.nums[$scope.randvar])<0)
    {
      console.log("inside if"+$scope.arr.indexOf($scope.arr[$scope.arr]));
      console.log("array elem"+$scope.nums[$scope.randvar]);
      $scope.arr.push($scope.nums[$scope.randvar]);
      b=$scope.arr.length;
      console.log("push successful")
    }
 }
 for(var i=0;i<$scope.arr.length;i++)
 {
    console.log($scope.arr[i]+" ");
 }
```